# Java cast base class to an extended class

Tags: java

i have a class that is used widely in my project as some sort of field holder. Something like:

```
class A
{
    private String field = null;
    private String field2 = null;
    private String field3 = null;

    // and its generic Getters and Setters
}
```

In certain part of code i need add additional fields to this class. So i did this

```
class B extends A
{
    private String fieldInB  = null;

    // and its Getters and Setters
}
```

in my function i thought i could easily do

```
public void foo( A a )
{
    B b = (B)a;
}
```

And i could have all the fields written in `a`object and i could easily set only field in `b` and use it. This seams like a common problem, but i just don't know how to do it except with an very ugly approach:

```
public B( A a )
{
    // copy all the fields one at the time
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/). It allows to map bean property values from one bean class to another.

Comment: Well i looked into it, and this seems this could be the thing i was asking for. Thx

Answer (score 4):

You areconfusing different parts of Java:

```
B b = (B)a;
```

this is classical class cast, but to work with `B` class object you need:

1. be sure that `a` is of `B` class (check it with `instanceof` java keyword:

```
if (a instanceof B) {
   B b = (B) a;
}
```

2. or wrap `a` in `B` class object (create `B` class object with copying fields from `a`).

PS in most of Java coding conventions it is recommended to fill fields by concrete values only (and not fill with default JavaVM values - `null`s)

Comfortable way to copy `A` class fields to new instance:

```
public A (A a) {
   this.field = a.field;
   this.field2 = a.field2;
   this.field3 = a.field3;
}
```

and for B class:

```
public B (A a) {
   super(a);
}
```

Another way - some libraries that will work with `A` class and `B` class as with beans. Sample of this libraries you can find in Toilal's answer

Comment: Well my problem is that `a` is not `instanceof B` but i want to make it one, without making a "copying constructor". I have to do this for several classes, and I just thought that there could be an easier way...

Comment: You may create constructor for class `A` that will copy all fields to new instance and create constructor for class `B` that will call this `A` class constructor... I'll add samples in my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Hai john Actually i didn't get your exact requirement.  I recon the way you have written this code is not right.
Private variable cant be inherited.If you need  to  extend values to your subclass you should have declared those variables as public.

```
public B(A a)
{
super.field=a.field;
super.field2=a.field2;
super.field3=a.field3;
}
```

Comment: Well i thought i could access them via their public Getters and Setters.

Considering your answer, i know i can do this, i just thought that there could be an easier way. without physically mapping the fields one at the time

Comment: Please don't write such wrong samples: such constructor should be of `A` class and `B` constructor should only call `super(a)` constructor!